# Need to request forget password in Wordpress for a user programatically

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a function in WordPress that I can pass a user name to and that would reset its password and send an email with new login details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the two neat WordPress functions `wp_new_user_notification()` and `wp_set_password()`.

The first notify the blog administrator of a new user, normally via email and **also send an email with login/password** to the new user. The second updates the user's password with a new **encrypted** one.

**Usage:**

```
 <?php wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass ) ?>
```

and

```
<?php wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ) ?>
```

Documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_password_change_notification).

Comment: I am sorry but do you mean to use wp_new_user_notification() or (which makes more sense from your documentation link) wp_password_change_notification ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ) ?>
```

in which you can specify $password = anything you want.

and then after **wp_mail** to send mail to user.

Comment: I am using SMTP for mailing ...  does WP handle that , so I can still use wp_mail ? Need to wait if someone else will give me what I am looking for ... before I choose this as the best answer